# IE plugins support

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, browser-plugin

I have been looking for a cut off date for Internet Explorer plugin support. In Windows 8 the IE (Metro) disables almost all ActiveX controls.

Chrome will not be taking anymore submissions for plugins and eventually will no longer support plugins by the end of 2014 ([Chrome-May2014](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/05/update-on-npapi-deprecation.html?m=1), [Chrome-Sept2013](http://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html)).

Firefox has went to a click to activate solution, but I did not find where they are not supporting plugins ([Mozilla-Sept2013](https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2013/09/24/plugin-activation-in-firefox/)). They are suggesting that developers avoid using plugins.

Has anyone seen a cut off date for IE?

Comment: Within 3 minutes I got a down vote response? I did show that I researched the question and it seems IMO clear and useful for future development of plugins. At least provide a comment of why or what could be improved, instead of drive by down-voting questions.

Comment: There are no plans now to remove plugin support from Firefox. There are enough plugins still being used and transitions will take a long time. I haven't heard anything about stopping plugin support for IE either. Still, writing new plugins should be seriously considered due to the above reasons and prevalence of mobile.